# Where has gone Anti-aliasing in 2.8+?

Tags: interface, antialiasing

We used to have the Anti-Aliasing section in the Render settings in the Properties Editor back in `2.7-` :

[image]

I was wondering where it went in `2.8+`.

I have already seen [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/158564/115533) and its answer but I don't think it's the one I am looking for since they pointed for `Render->Film->Filter` (for cycles it's `Pixel Filter`) and that section only has the `Size` and the Algorithm and there is no options for the amount of anti-aliasing samples :

[image]

and also the algorithms' lists are completely different :

[image]

[image]

That makes me think that may be it's not what I am looking for.

Does anyone has an explanation about this? Have they dropped anti-aliasing in `2.8`? If not where can I chose the amount of anti-aliasing samples?

Answer (score 1):

The `Scene->Sampling` settings seems to control anti-aliasing samples now, while the `Pixel Filter` setting you mentioned affects the strength of the blurring AA causes.

In Cycles, the Min Samples setting says it affects AA.

[image: Cycles Min Samples Setting]

Eevee doesn't seem to explicitly state that it affects AA anywhere in Blender, but from my testing it seems to have a similar effect when you change the sampling level and combine it with `Pixel Filter`.

Edit: I did some more digging and found a bit more info on how AA is handled now. The documentation states that [Eevee directly uses the current sample count for Temporal anti-aliasing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/render/eevee/render_settings/sampling.html), while [Cycles adjusts samples automatically based on how much noise an area has](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html).

Comment: I'm not sure but I think there is a confusion between rendering samples and Anti-aliasing samples. Noise Threshold is the maximum amount of noise allowed before stopping the render and Max Samples is the max number of samples allowed, if it is reached before Noise Threshold, the render stops, Min sample is the opposite, render won't stop before reaching this amount event if Noise Threshold is reached. I don't think they have something to do with Anti-Aliasing. They do reduce aliasing tho.

Comment: I don't think I'm confusing the two sampling types. Based on the documentation I linked, it seems that anti-aliasing is now dependent on rendering samples plus the pixel filter size rather than having the hardcoded 5, 8, 11, and 16 options from Blender 2.7. At least that's how it is for Eevee. I think the adaptive sampling system in Cycles is meant to replace traditional AA though, since it effectively does the same thing. I was mislead by the tooltip in Blender 3.0 still saying the sample count affects AA even though the 3.0 documentation I linked actually has no mention of AA.

Comment: This is where you confuse it, Anti-Aliasing is a post-processing effect while sampling is happening whilst rendering. And yes EEVEE uses samples for Anti-Aliasing but it is **Temporal Anti-Aliasing**, not just Anti-Aliasing. Temporal Anti-Aliasing happens during rendering but I am looking for the Post-process thing not the in-render thing. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Anti-aliasing is not restricted to post-processing. There is prefiltering and postfiltering (or supersampling), whereas prefiltering is a quite common method for anti-aliasing.

Comment: Yes I know, but the anti-aliasing from 2.7 is postfiltering and it's what I am looking for. More specifically, 2.7 used Multisample anti-aliasing which is kinda like Supersampling but faster since it only focuses on some regions of the image not the entire image.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka It's a difference to say someone's wrong because it's a post-processing effect or saying you're looking for the post-processing effect. Anyway, there is an _Anti-Aliasing_ node in the compositor which is a post effect, but I guess that's not what you want. I would suspect they just dropped it for other anti-aliasing methods, as Chromarict said it seems to be dependent on rendering samples now, at least this is what the glossary of the Blender Manual implies by saying "Anti-Aliasing: Is the technique of minimizing Aliasing, by e.g. rendering multiple samples per pixel."

Comment: Sorry if I was rude, I just wanted to point out the misunderstanding. I was looking for a old feature that I can't find anywhere in the new version and I tried to explain the difference between what he proposed and what I was looking for, that's all.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka As you said, it's an old feature and no longer available as it seems. I don't think Chromarict really misunderstood what you said, as he stated several times that what he explains is how AA is handled **now** in Blender. So, no misunderstanding - it might not be what you want but that's how it is today. I guess it is because of the changes in the render engines generally that this method is now better(?) or necessary(?). I don't know the technical reasons.

Comment: You may be right, I was just skeptical about it.